# Dynamically create checkbox from database using jsp spring mvc hibernate

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Business rule:
An event have many equipments and an equipment appears in many events.

I am trying to dynamically generate a checkbox based on the equipment table from the database. I will use this checkbox to add an event with many equipments. I have issue figuring out how to convert an equipment object in jsp to a Set(collection) and then add it the event model.

1. pull the equipment list form database.
2. pass that equipment list to jsp
3. convert the equipment list to a Set collection because an equipment is a Set in the event model.
4. Update the database so it can have an event with many equipments.

This is the event model.

```
public class Event {

private int eventId;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String eventName;
private String location;
private String description;
private Set<Equipment> lstEquipments = new HashSet<Equipment>();
private Set<Staff> lstStaffs = new HashSet<Staff>();
```

//getter and setting and constructors

This is the equipment model.

```
public class Equipment {

private int equipmentId;
private String equipment_Name;
private Set<Event> lstEvents = new HashSet<Event>();
```

//getter and setting

This is the jsp form.

```
        <table>
        <form:form action="saveEvent" method="POST"
            modelAttribute="eventModel">
            <form:hidden path="eventId" />
            <tr>
                <td>Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD) :</td>
                <td><form:input path="startDate" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="startDate" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Date(YYYY-MM-DD) :</td>
                <td><form:input path="endDate" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="endDate" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Event Name :</td>
                <td><form:input path="eventName" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="eventName" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location :</td>
                <td><form:input path="location" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="location" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description :</td>
                <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="description" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Equipments :</td>
                <td><form:checkboxes path="lstEquipments" items="${listEquipment}"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="lstEquipments" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Staffs :</td>
                <td><form:checkboxes path="lstStaffs" items="${listStaff}"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="lstStaffs" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
                    value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </form:form>
    </table>
```

This is the controller for the save event.

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/saveEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(ModelAndView mnv, @Valid @ModelAttribute("eventModel") Event event, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    //pull a list of available Equipments from the relational database.
    Set<Equipment> listEquipment = equipmentDAO.list();
    mnv.addObject("listEquipment", listEquipment);

    //pull a list of available Staffs from the relational database.
    Set<Staff> listStaff = staffDAO.list();
    mnv.addObject("listStaff", listStaff);

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        //pull a list of Event from DB for display in JSP.
        Set<Event> listEvent = eventDAO.list();
        mnv.addObject("listEvent", listEvent);

        mnv.addObject("eventModel", event);
        mnv.setViewName("index");
        return mnv;
    }

    //update the database with a new event.
    eventDAO.saveOrUpdate(event);

    //pull a list of Event from DB for display in JSP.
    Set<Event> listEvent = eventDAO.list();
    mnv.addObject("listEvent", listEvent);

    mnv.addObject("eventModel", new Event());
    mnv.setViewName("index");
    return mnv;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form:checkboxes tag where you are outputting the equipment, make sure to specify the itemLabel and itemValue attributes like so:

```
<form:checkboxes path="lstEquipments" items="${listEquipment}" itemLabel="equipment_Name" itemValue="equipmentId"/>
```

Now in your save method, you have the unique identifier for each selected equipment. You can access those IDs (from the lstEquipment property of your mnv object) and get their full name from the database so you can create a bunch of Equipment objects and add those to a set and put that set into an Event object.